# Displaying inner forms elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have taken a form in which there is a select tag. And there is a div which is displayed none. So what I want is that if I select the option value saab the div should get displayed. So how can i do this.Is there any way to this via php or jquery . Please help me with this. I also tried the script for this but failed.

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#even').click(function(){
                $('#hqr').fadeIn();
            });
    });
   </script>
```

Is this the correct script to do this or there is some other technique?

```
<form action="index1.html#!/registration">
<select>
    <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" id="even">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi" id="even">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="hqr" style="width:20%;height:20%;border:solid black thick;display:none;">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Comment: even Ids repeat one more time!

Comment: `id="even"` for Saab and Audi

Comment: @SonakshiSharma they are *not* unique: more than one element on your page has the same ID. This is not allowed. If you want to apply an identifier to *more than one* element, use a `class` instead of an `id`, then refer to it in your jQuery as `.even` instead of `#even`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ID of an element must be unique** so instead of using id you can use a `data-*` property to indicate elements which need to display the `hqr` element.

Also you need to listen to the select elements change event

```
<form action="index1.html#!/registration">
    <select id="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab" data-type="even">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi" data-type="even">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hqr" style="width:20%;height:20%;border:solid black thick;display:none;"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select').change(function () {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').is('[data-type="even"]')) {
            $('#hqr').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#hqr').fadeOut();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kb7h6/)

---

If you want to display the `hqr` element bases on the option's position odd/event then you can use a easier solution using `:nth-child(even)` selector instead of `data-type="even"`

```
<form action="index1.html#!/registration">
    <select id="select">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hqr" style="width:20%;height:20%;border:solid black thick;display:none;"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select').change(function () {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').is(':nth-child(even)')) {
            $('#hqr').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#hqr').fadeOut();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m3368/)

Comment: Any reason for `data-` over `class` here? I would've thought a `class` would be more sensible, simpler and faster, but happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: @Shai no particular reason... since `class` does not have any particular meaning in `option` element opted for `data-*`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of id="even" use class="even"

and your js must be like this

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.even').click(function(){
            $('#hqr').fadeIn();
        });
      });
</script>
```